# Why is number().min() not working in Yup validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

Here is my Yup schema. The validation on asset works fine, but I'm not sure why it is not working on the amount?

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      asset: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
      amount: Yup.number()
        .required()
        .min(5, "Must be more than 5")
        .positive(),
    });
```

Comment: You need to drop `positive()` in order for it work.

Comment: Ahhhhhh thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You may add `number.min(1, '')` & `number.max(1,'')`.
To specify the minimum and maximum quantity also

Answer (score 0):

```
<Typography color="error.main">
   { errors?.bonus_add }
</Typography>
```

...

```
 bonus_add: yup.number()
    .test('numbers', 'Допустимы только цифры', value => !value || /^[0-9]+$/.test(value))
    .test('lessThanTen', 'Поле “Количество бонусов” должно содержать не более 9 символов', value => !value || value.toString().length < 10)
    .required('Обязательное поле'),
```